# Java: systematically ignore certain 4-letter words randomly chosen from a dictionary?

Tags: java

This one is sort of weird. The code I'm writing is for a particular word game, so it's very specialized.

I've got a `HashMap<Integer, String>` which at runtime contains 4036 indexed 4-letter words. In the same class, I also have a method `random()` which will randomly select a word from said `HashMap`. This is the word that the player starts with. He or she will then change the word 1 letter at a time to form new, valid words. e.g., *FIVE* -> *FIRE* -> *WIRE* -> *WISE* -> *WISH* -> *etc*. Obviously, I don't want the first word chosen to start the player off to be unchangeable (i.e. there are no words to be made from changing one letter).

So, I need a different method which checks to see if the randomly chosen word meets this criterion. I'm guessing I'll need to iterate through all 4036 entries. That's easy enough, but how can I check to see if there are any words that are exactly 1 letter off from the randomly chosen word?

Comment: You could also store you words in groups - for example the group `FI?E` would contain `FIVE` and `FIRE`. You can then store them in a `Map<String, List<String>>` for example, where the key is `FI?E` and the list all the items in that group. When you pick a word randomly, say `FIVE`, you can then check if one of the possible groups `?IVE`, `F?VE`, `FI?E`, `FIV?` contains more than one word. In that case, the `FI?E` group contains more than one word (it also has `FIRE`) so you can use it.

Comment: That is also a very smart solution I hadn't thought about. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take both words, and compare them letter-for-letter. Since identical letters must be in the same position, this requires only a single loop that checks no more than four letters. Every time you see a difference, increment a counter. If the counter reaches 2, the words differ in more than one position. If the counter equals one after the loop through the four characters is over, you have two words that differ in exactly one position:

```
boolean differByOne(String w1, String w2) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
        if (w1.charAt(i) != w2.charAt(i)) count++;
        if (count > 1) return false;
    }
    return count == 1;
}
```

Comment: Feeling stupid again. The task went from daunting, to me sort of understanding the process while I was writing my question, to having an epiphany! Haha! Thanks a bunch!